# Zxing - Integrating in PHP

Tags: php, zxing, barcode-scanner

I want to decode QRCode/Barcode and i have been searching around for a while,
zxing has a webservice [here](http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx) but it is not an API so i cant massively use for my own purpose. But zxing has an open source library.
Can any one help me how can i integrate it with my own php code?is there any way at all?
I also found [php-zbarcode](https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zbarcode) but it seems that it is discontinued.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find out one, but could not find one. So I wrote one myself.

https://github.com/dsiddharth2/php-zxing

Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to scan QR Code. It can select both the front and back camera in mobile. This is set to the back camera in devices with 2 cameras.

https://github.com/schmich/instascan/

```
<?php
    if(isset($_COOKIE['myJavascriptVar']))
    {
       $phpVar =  $_COOKIE['myJavascriptVar'];





    enter code here

    ?>

    <html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/schmich/instascan-builds/master/instascan.min.js" ></script> 
</head>
    <body>



                    <h3 class="text-center" style="font-family: sans-serif;">Scan the QR Code by Placing the code in front your camera</h3>

        <video  id="preview"></video>



        <script>

            let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner(
                {
                    video: document.getElementById('preview')
                }
            );
            scanner.addListener('scan', function(content) {
                alert('QR Code Scanned Successfully: ' + content);

                document.cookie = "myJavascriptVar = " + content;

                var phpID = "<?php echo $actID ?>"; 
                window.location.href = "qrCode?id="+phpID;
            });
            Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(cameras => 
            {
                if(cameras.length = 2){
                    scanner.start(cameras[1]);
                }
                 if(cameras.length = 1){
                    scanner.start(cameras[0]);
                } else {
                    console.error("Device does have have available or working camera!");
                }
            });



        </script>

     </body>
    </html>
```